# Ruby on Rails - CanCan user is nil during destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I'm getting cancan with devise wired into my first Ruby on Rails app. I have some of it working, but I hit a problem  my newbie brain cannot seem to understand.

I'm trying to delete a project model.  The cancan ability.initialize call is not working because the user is passed as nil even though I am logged in and other calls successfully authorize

In my show view, I have this link:

```
<%= link_to "Purge this project", @project, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "There is no way to get it back. Are you sure you want to permanently remove this project?"} %>
```

I think my controller is wired up correctly, other actions are properly authorized

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  ...
  def destroy
    puts "***********removing: " + params.inspect 
    @project.destroy
    ...
  end
```

My cancan initialize does this:

```
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user
    puts "********  Evaluating cancan permissions for: " + user.inspect
    ...
```

When I click the delete link above, this gets puts'ed to the console (notice how user.id is nil, this is caused because i setup the guest if user is nil)

```
********  Evaluating cancan permissions for: #<User id: nil, email: ""...
Started DELETE "/projects/16" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-04 10:48:23 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"16"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

PROBLEM:   Why is the user nil???  Is it related to the CSRF token issue?  Is there something special about http method=delete that I'm missing?  How can I stop the dumb, it hurts?

The preceding "show" action yielded this expected puts (concluding stuff should be wired up sufficiently):

```
********  Evaluating cancan permissions for: #<User id: 2, email: "doug...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self answer warning!  So, I guess delete actions need to happen within a form post in order for the identity and CSRF stuff to be handled correctly?!?

Replacing my link with a form made things work again:

```
<%= form_for @project, :method => :delete do  %>   
  <%= submit_tag "Purge this project", confirm: "Are you sure you want to permanently remove this project?" %> 
<% end %>
```